# is it possible to install multiple versions of dotnet framework using chef ms_dotnet cookbook?

Tags: .net, chef-infra, cookbook

I am trying to install dotnet 4.7 using chef ms_dotnet cookbook ( https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ms_dotnet#readme ) on windows 2012 R2 win box. However, the ms_dotnet install recipe keeps skipping because of not_if guard. The box already has dotnet 4.5.1 installed on it. Is it possible to not skip recipe and install 4.7 using ms_dotnet cookbook in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the recipes are only set up for each major version, but you can probably use the underlying custom resource directly. Take a look at the 4.x recipe, copy that code to your own wrapper of some kind and tweak it to install the specific version you are looking for.